# Run JBOSS EAP 6.4 as a Linux service as non-root user without password

Tags: linux, authentication, jboss, jboss-eap-6, sudoers

I would like to run JBOSS EAP 6.4 as a linux service using user "jboss" without using password. Currently when I am issuing command "service jboss start" I am being prompted for password.  I have created file called "jboss" under `/etc/init.d/` and it looks like this

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# JBoss standalone control script
#
# chkconfig: - 80 20
# description: JBoss EAP Standalone
# processname: standalone
# pidfile: /usr/local/jboss-eap-6.4/jboss-eap-standalone.pid
# config: /usr/local/jboss-eap-6.4/bin/standalone.conf

# Source function library.
. /etc/init.d/functions

export JBOSS_USER=jboss

# Load Java configuration.
[ -r /etc/java/java.conf ] && . /etc/java/java.conf
export JAVA_HOME

# Load JBoss AS init.d configuration.
if [ -z "$JBOSS_CONF" ]; then
  JBOSS_CONF=“/usr/local/jboss-eap-6.4/bin/standalone.conf"
fi

[ -r "$JBOSS_CONF" ] && . "${JBOSS_CONF}"

# Set defaults.

if [ -z "$JBOSS_HOME" ]; then
  JBOSS_HOME=/usr/local/jboss-eap-6.4
fi
export JBOSS_HOME

if [ -z "$JBOSS_PIDFILE" ]; then
  JBOSS_PIDFILE=/usr/local/jboss-eap-6.4/jboss-eap-standalone.pid
fi
export JBOSS_PIDFILE

if [ -z "$JBOSS_CONSOLE_LOG" ]; then
  JBOSS_CONSOLE_LOG=/usr/local/jboss-eap-6.4/standalone/log/console.log
fi

if [ -z "$STARTUP_WAIT" ]; then
  STARTUP_WAIT=30
fi

if [ -z "$SHUTDOWN_WAIT" ]; then
  SHUTDOWN_WAIT=30
fi

if [ -z "$JBOSS_CONFIG" ]; then
  JBOSS_CONFIG=standalone-full.xml
fi

JBOSS_SCRIPT=$JBOSS_HOME/bin/standalone.sh

prog='jboss-eap-6.4'

CMD_PREFIX=''

if [ ! -z "$JBOSS_USER" ]; then
  if [ -r /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions ]; then
    CMD_PREFIX="daemon --user $JBOSS_USER"
    else
    CMD_PREFIX="su - $JBOSS_USER -c"
  fi
fi

start() {
  echo -n "Starting $prog: "
  if [ -f $JBOSS_PIDFILE ]; then
    read ppid < $JBOSS_PIDFILE
    if [ `ps --pid $ppid 2> /dev/null | grep -c $ppid 2> /dev/null` -eq '1' ]; then
      echo -n "$prog is already running"
      failure
      echo
      return 1
    else
      rm -f $JBOSS_PIDFILE
    fi
  fi
  mkdir -p $(dirname $JBOSS_CONSOLE_LOG)
  cat /dev/null > $JBOSS_CONSOLE_LOG

  mkdir -p $(dirname $JBOSS_PIDFILE)
  chown $JBOSS_USER $(dirname $JBOSS_PIDFILE) || true
  #$CMD_PREFIX JBOSS_PIDFILE=$JBOSS_PIDFILE $JBOSS_SCRIPT 2>&1 > $JBOSS_CONSOLE_LOG &
  #$CMD_PREFIX JBOSS_PIDFILE=$JBOSS_PIDFILE $JBOSS_SCRIPT &

  if [ ! -z "$JBOSS_USER" ]; then
    if [ -r /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions ]; then
      daemon --user $JBOSS_USER LAUNCH_JBOSS_IN_BACKGROUND=1 JBOSS_PIDFILE=$JBOSS_PIDFILE $JBOSS_SCRIPT -c $JBOSS_CONFIG > $JBOSS_CONSOLE_LOG 2>&1 &
      else
      su - $JBOSS_USER -c "LAUNCH_JBOSS_IN_BACKGROUND=1 JBOSS_PIDFILE=$JBOSS_PIDFILE $JBOSS_SCRIPT -c $JBOSS_CONFIG" > $JBOSS_CONSOLE_LOG 2>&1 &
    fi
  fi

  count=0
  launched=false

  until [ $count -gt $STARTUP_WAIT ]
  do
    grep 'JBAS015961:' $JBOSS_CONSOLE_LOG > /dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
      launched=true
      break
    fi
    sleep 1
    let count=$count+1;
  done

  if [ "$launched" = "false" ] ; then
    echo "$prog failed to startup in the time allotted"
    failure
    echo
    return 7
  fi

  success
  echo
 return 0
}

stop() {
  echo -n $"Stopping $prog: "
  count=0;

  if [ -f $JBOSS_PIDFILE ]; then
    read kpid < $JBOSS_PIDFILE
    let kwait=$SHUTDOWN_WAIT

    # Try issuing SIGTERM

    kill -15 $kpid
    until [ `ps --pid $kpid 2> /dev/null | grep -c $kpid 2> /dev/null` -eq '0' ] || [ $count -gt $kwait ]
    do
      sleep 1
      let count=$count+1;
    done

    if [ $count -gt $kwait ]; then
      kill -9 $kpid
    fi
  fi
  rm -f $JBOSS_PIDFILE
  success
  echo
}

status() {
  if [ -f $JBOSS_PIDFILE ]; then
  read ppid < $JBOSS_PIDFILE
    if [ `ps --pid $ppid 2> /dev/null | grep -c $ppid 2> /dev/null` -eq '1' ]; then
      echo "$prog is running (pid $ppid)"
      return 0
    else
      echo "$prog dead but pid file exists"
      return 1
    fi
  fi
  echo "$prog is not running"
  return 3
}

case "$1" in
  start)
      start
      ;;
  stop)
      stop
      ;;
  restart)
      $0 stop
      $0 start
      ;;
  status)
      status
      ;;
  *)
      ## If no parameters are given, print which are avaiable.
      echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|restart|reload}"
      exit 1
      ;;
esac
```

My */etc/sudoers* file has following entries

```
ALL ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /bin/su - jboss
ALL ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /sbin/service jboss start 
ALL ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /sbin/service jboss stop
ALL ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /sbin/service jboss status
```

JBOSS location = */usr/local/jboss-eap-6.4* and following are the permission on this

```
drwxrwxr-x. 11 jboss jboss 236 Mar 27  2015 jboss-eap-6.4
```

Permission on `/etc/init.d/jboss`

```
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  3917 Aug  6 16:23 jboss
```

Comment: As which user do you run "service jboss start"?

Comment: When I run it as root user it runs fine no issues. But I would like to run it as user jboss without entering password and when I use sudo in front of service command logged in as jboss user I am being prompted for sudo password for user jboss.

Comment: Shouldn't you enter /etc/init.d/service in /etc/sudoers?